# NRI Indian customs question

Tags: india, customs

Though info is avaliable online but I am not sure as it talks about Indian residents returning to India for good.

I am a Singapore resident staying here for last 2 years. I keep travelling to India. This time I am carrying some new electronics of value not more than Rs. 50k. Is that within the limits?

My fiance who is a British citizen but OCI India is also carrying a phone worth Rs. 50k and a camera lens worth Rs. 30k

will such items be asked for customs for her and for me?

Comment: "50k" in what currency?

Comment: Currency is Indian rupees

Comment: I don't know about for india specifically but when bringing expensive goods into a country it often makes a big difference whether the goods are intended to stay in the country.